# convertir timespan a datetime y agregar a un datetimerpicker

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

Quiero mostrar un tipo de datos de intervalo de tiempo en un datatimerpicker, primero debo convertir, pero no sé cómo hacerlo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
        TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);

        TimeSpan r = b - a;
        TimeSpan rr = new TimeSpan(r.Ticks / 2);

        MessageBox.Show("Test\n " + rr);   ///this is type TimeSpan 

        dateTimePicker.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(rr);   /// ERROR" Additional Information: An object of type 'System.TimeSpan' can not be converted to type 'System.IConvertible'. "
    }
```

Comment: Que dato buscas que se vea en el DateTimePicker, es decir, con que fecha vas a trabajar para añadir el TimeSpan?

Comment: No tengo clara la pregunta, quieres que el datetimepicker solo tenga un rango determinado de fechas para escoger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto: `dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now + rr;`

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276228/timespan-to-datetime-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Debido a  que timespan es un rango de tiempo, no puede ser convertido directamente a datetime, lo que debes hacer es tomar una fecha base y a esta sumarle tu timespan, ej :

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01);
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
myDate = myDate + myTimeSpan;
```